# Binning files based on the values in python

Tags: python, binning

I am trying to bin the values into some custom bins for my data. The Coulmn1 in the dataframe consists of a large set of random numbers ranging from 1.4 to 1.9. 
Suppose the initial dataframe looks like this:

```
Index    Col1
1        1.4678
2        1.5001
3        1.5795
4        1.5234 
...      ......
98       1.6754
99       1.6399
100      1.4910
```

What I want to do is to bin the numbers that fall within +/- 0.002 of the bins listed below. i.e., I want to bin all the data that fall within 1.458 and 1.462 for the first bin. The output should look like this

```
Index    Col1       Bin_names
1        1.4678      NaN
2        1.5001      1.50
3        1.5795      1.58
4        1.5234      NaN
...      ......      ....
98       1.6754      NaN
99       1.6399      1.64
100      1.4910      NaN
```

I tried the code below, but it bins all the data between 1.46 to 1.48 in one bin, which is not what I want.

```
bins = [1.46,1.48,1.5,1.52,1.54,1.56,1.58,1.60,1.62,1.64,1.66,1.68,1.70]
df['Bin_names'] = pd.cut(df['Column1'], bins, labels=['1.48','1.5','1.52','1.54','1.56','1.58','1.60','1.62','1.64','1.66','1.68','1.70'])
```

How can I bin the data based on my requirement?

Comment: Can you provide an expected output on an example? For example in which bin falls 1.467?

Comment: @fmarm I have updated the question with how the final dataframe should look like.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the boundary of `pd.cut()` contains the right edge, so you can start with the label '1.46'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
random.seed(10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[round(random.uniform(1.450, 1.700),4) for i in range(100)]}, index=np.arange(1,101,1))

bins = [1.46,1.48,1.50,1.52,1.54,1.56,1.58,1.60,1.62,1.64,1.66,1.68,1.70]
labels = ['1.46','1.48','1.50','1.52','1.54','1.56','1.58','1.60','1.62','1.64','1.66','1.68']

df['Bin_names'] = pd.cut(df['Col1'], bins, labels=labels,right=False)
df.sort_values('Col1', inplace=True)
df2 = df.groupby('Bin_names').agg(list)
df3 = df2['Col1'].apply(pd.Series)
df3['cnt'] = df3.count(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
df3


       0    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  cnt
Bin_names                                                   
1.46    1.4611  1.4611  1.4657  1.4662  1.4700  1.4742  1.4782  1.4799  NaN NaN NaN NaN 8
1.48    1.4832  1.4835  1.4874  1.4891  1.4901  1.4912  1.4914  1.4916  1.4946  NaN NaN NaN 9
1.50    1.5015  1.5061  1.5104  1.5114  1.5125  1.5187  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 6
1.52    1.5209  1.5257  1.5286  1.5299  1.5319  1.5329  1.5369  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7
1.54    1.5415  1.5435  1.5454  1.5476  1.5503  1.5532  1.5535  1.5551  1.5572  1.5583  1.5587  1.5590  12
1.56    1.5603  1.5620  1.5639  1.5642  1.5654  1.5700  1.5723  1.5725  1.5742  NaN NaN NaN 9
1.58    1.5800  1.5802  1.5813  1.5834  1.5847  1.5872  1.5918  1.5929  1.5945  1.5957  1.5961  1.5962  12
1.60    1.6003  1.6005  1.6008  1.6033  1.6043  1.6122  1.6134  1.6145  1.6155  1.6183  1.6187  NaN 11
1.62    1.6215  1.6281  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2
1.64    1.6420  1.6439  1.6444  1.6519  1.6533  1.6545  1.6553  1.6559  NaN NaN NaN NaN 8
1.66    1.6610  1.6638  1.6650  1.6674  1.6745  1.6776  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 6
1.68    1.6853  1.6869  1.6882  1.6922  1.6923  1.6956  1.6991  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 7
```